# Good way to express dynamic records in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures

What might be a good practice to express dynamic records in C++?

I am trying to write a code which handles dynamic records which the length of the record differs from it's type. The target that I'm expressing does not have much operations to apply to, and may be accessed directly from the programmer, so I think it should be a `struct` rather than a `class` .

The size of the record is fixed on construction, and the number of record may exist from hundreds to tens of millions per execution.

I think I have three options. First is to use a fixed size array for having the length of maximum possible items of the records. The maximum possible length is known and the length varies from 1 to maximum 10. 
*edited: the records has some common entries*

Second option is to make a dynamic array for each records. In this case, should it be better to use `std::vector` rather than manipulating the allocation myself? Or is using STL always better than implementing it myself?

Third option is to use inheritance with polymorphism. I don't want to actually do this because there is not much "common" operations or even any operations to be applied with.

Another functionality that I want is, as it is going to be a record I want to be accessible with a string or at least a name-like method. This is not mandatory but I think this might be good for future code readability. I could use a `std::map` instead of a dynamic array or `std::vector` I thought in this case I would like some get/setter like C# properties(which C++ does not have).

So I have few things to consider. One thing is the readability of future code. If I sacrifice the readability, then I could just access records by indexes, not by names. Another thing is performance and the memory usage. I want to avoid highly the "string" comparison operation that might occur during std::map and also want to use the least amount of memory since there are lots of records to handle with.

Until now, while doing some personal project I do have think a while when it comes to choosing which data structure to use, but actually the reasoning was not good. Please share your insights or it would be best if you recommend me a literature to read (Not only which has topics with generic algorithm and data-structure stuff but also with real coding practice and may explain in-depth STL).

Edited: I am keeping a log of the behavior of an AI. The AI goes through a 2d space. I am trying to log the behavior of every AI. The character(AI) could be generated, deleted, enter room, leave room, could kill other AIs and also can be killed and so on. I am trying to make a log of the behaviors. (Not all) but some records are..

```
Type_Enter_Room : LogType | AI_ID | Room_ID | EnterTime
Type_Leave_Room : LogType | AI_ID | Room_ID | LeaveTime
Type_Attack_AI  : LogType | AttackerAI_ID | TargetAI_ID | AttackTime | Location
Type_AI_Dead    : LogType | AI_ID | DeadTime | DeadPlace
```

The records share some items, but also have different entries. And all of the records should be in memory to perform the operation that I want to apply.

Comment: If size is fixed on construction, you can also use the new operator to create the array you need and keep a pointer to it.

Comment: Some code examples of the desired interface could help.

Comment: Can you show a couple of concrete examples of such dynamic records? (Doesn't need to be valid C++). What kind of application they are useful for?

Comment: @n.m I added a short example of the record types.

Comment: It looks like each record type has a fixed set of fields. Why not create a plain old class for each record type? All records have ID and/or creation timestamp in common, these could go in their common base class. One of those can be a key in std:::map that keeps all the records. An obvious common operation is displaying/writing to a file. Other operations can be implemented out-of-class using the visitor pattern.

Comment: Maybe the example was not showing the problem well. There are common fields as you can see, but are also many different types that does not share the fields. And furthermore, the number of types is more than a dozen. Even for this case, do you think it might be the best way to do it with class inheritance?

Comment: Looks like an Entity Component System.

Comment: If you care more about performance than memory usage, you can have an enum of all behaviors in order to both be able to use integer indices as well as having readable code. Then have the array be the size of the enum, even for types that don't use all of the fields. This also lets you define the array size in the code, and not have to do it dynamically

Comment: You meed to define each record type somehow, somewhere. Why not as a class?